# How to "un-deprecate" an installation in Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, ide, deprecated

I want to use `RSE Terminals UI` - but it is being deprecated and shows the following message:

```
Note: This feature is deprecated. 
Use the "Remote System Explorer Terminals View add-in" 
feature from the "Mobile and Device Development" category instead.
```

I assume I need to disable/uninstall this add-in, but I couldn't find it.